# How to install grub bootloader as second stage bootloader

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, arm, u-boot

As you know `grub` bootloader supports arm architecture on recent versions,but it demands EFI ,thing that is unavaible on most arm base single board computers (SBCs) and they use [`U-boot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) instead of EFI therefore
grub released an ability to act as second stage bootloader after  U-boot first stage bootloader, but I don't know how to install it as second stage on my device.

my device is Orange pi 3 with [AllWinner H6 (ARMv8 , Cortex-A53)](https://linux-sunxi.org/H6) processor with U-boot default bootloader ,so how can I install `grub` as second stage?

Comment: The most important question is, can this CPU+U-Boot combination run 32-bit ARM code? If it can, you should be able to use "grub-mkimage --target=arm-uboot" to build a Grub image that will be bootable by U-Boot. Otherwise you will need to develop support for a new Grub build target "arm64-uboot", probably heavily imitating the 32-bit "arm-uboot". Once you have the image, just place it where U-Boot can reach it and tell U-Boot to boot that image instead of the Linux kernel.

Comment: @telcoM The Armv8(ARM64) has backward compatibility with the  ARMv7(ARMhf) so I think `--target=arm-uboot` could do the  job for my device, couldn't it?