# How u-boot can chain "grub" and booting a mainline kernel on my ARM Chromebook

Tags: ubuntu, grub, arm, u-boot

I would like to enable KVM virtualization on my old ARM Chromebook laptop,based on the Exynos5250 arm 32 bit cpu aka snow,model xe303c12. The first thing I did has been to dd the image below directly on the sd card :

https://github.com/hexdump0815/imagebuilder/releases/download/220619-01/chromebook_snow-armv7l-jammy.img.gz

and it worked like a charm,but kvm was disabled. So,I have started to look for a good documentation to understand how to enable kvm and I found this :

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/en/solutions/guides/kvm-on-chromebook/

I've followed all the instructions and it worked,but only with Ubuntu 13.04 and 14.04. More upgraded ubuntu versions give a lot of problems and they don't work.

So,I've thought about a fresh idea. What about to install the virtual open systems "non-verified u-boot" on the first partition like explained in the tutorial,and,instead of starting another u-boot after the original,can I chain grub with the kernel installed for example by the ubuntu jammy iso image created by "hexdump0815" ? To be honest I'm not sure if hexdump0815 used grub,but I will explain this later.

Anyway,I've got the idea by reading here :

[How to install grub bootloader as second stage bootloader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599141/how-to-install-grub-bootloader-as-second-stage-bootloader)

So,now,I'm going to explain what's the content of the partitions on my Frankenstein sd card.

**1) /dev/sdh1 = unknown = 16 MB. I've created this partition by doing :**

```
$ dd if=nv_uboot-snow.kpart of=/dev/sdh1
```

Where I've got the file nv_uboot-snow.kpart ? From here :

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/downloads/guides/kvm_on_chromebook/nv_u-boot-snow.kpart

**2) /dev/sdh2 = unknown = 16 MB. This partition has been created by executing the following script :**

```
$ ./scripts/sdcard.sh /dev/sdh
```

**3) /dev/sdh3 = ext2 = BOOT**

Inside the partition /dev/sdh3 I have copied the following files and folders (taken
from the hexdump0815 "chromebook_snow-armv7l-jammy.img.gz" file :

> a) dtb-5.18.1-stb-cbe+ = directory
>
> b) extlinux = directory
>
> c) extra = directory
>
> d) config.5.18.1-stb-cbe+ : file
>
> e) initrd.img-5.18.1-stb-cbe+ : file
>
> f) System.map-5.18.1-stb-cbe+ : file
>
> g) vmlinux.kpart-5.18.1-stb-cbe+ : file
>
> h) zImage-5.18.1-stb.cbe+ : file

Inside the directory "dtb-5.18.1-stb-cbe+" there are the following files :

> a) exynos5250-snow.dtb
>
> b) exynos5250-snow-rev5.dtb
>
> c) exynos5250-spring.dtb

Inside the directory "extlinux",there is the following file :

a) extlinux.conf : that has the following content :

```
TIMEOUT 30

DEFAULT linux-snow-rev4

MENU TITLE snow chromebook boot options

# rev4 snow chromebook
LABEL linux-snow-rev4
      MENU LABEL linux rev4 snow
      LINUX ../zImage-5.18.1-stb-cbe+
      INITRD ../initrd.img-5.18.1-stb-cbe+
      FDT ../dtb-5.18.1-stb-cbe+/exynos5250-snow.dtb
      APPEND console=tty1 root=LABEL=rootpart ro rootwait net.ifnames=0 ipv6.disable=1 fsck.repair=yes noresume

# rev5 snow chromebook
LABEL linux-snow-rev5
      MENU LABEL linux rev5 snow
      LINUX ../zImage-5.18.1-stb-cbe+
      INITRD ../initrd.img-5.18.1-stb-cbe+
      FDT ../dtb-5.18.1-stb-cbe+/exynos5250-snow-rev5.dtb
      APPEND console=tty1 root=LABEL=rootpart ro rootwait net.ifnames=0 ipv6.disable=1 fsck.repair=yes noresume

# spring chromebook - untested
LABEL linux-spring
      MENU LABEL linux spring
      LINUX ../zImage-5.18.1-stb-cbe+
      INITRD ../initrd.img-5.18.1-stb-cbe+
      # rev4 snow chromebook
      FDT ../dtb-5.18.1-stb-cbe+/exynos5250-spring.dtb
      APPEND console=tty1 root=LABEL=rootpart ro rootwait net.ifnames=0 ipv6.disable=1 fsck.repair=yes noresume
```

Inside the extra directory there are the following files :

> a) kernel-chromebook_snow-legacy.tar.gz
>
> b) uboot.kpart.cbe-snow
>
> c) uboot.kpart.cbe-snow-alternative
>
> d) uboot.kpart.cbe-spring

**4) /dev/sdh4 : inside here I have copied all the files of the jammy userland prepared by hexdump0818.**

That's all. What I want to do is if and how can I chainload the "non-verified u-boot"
that is installed on the partition /dev/sdh1 with grub or whatever mechanism it is able to boot the hexdump0815 jammy iso image.

As I repeat,the "non-verified u-boot" is produced by the script called "build.sh",that's stored inside the u-boot/scripts directory. And if what I want to do is impossible,can you explain to me how I can enable kvm on my chromebook arm,using the most recent kernel possible ? I already know that the support for kvm on arm 32 has been dropped on kernel 5.7,but for me to use a lower kernel than 5.7 is ok. I've been working on this project for a lot of months. I would like to see some progress. Thanks.

PS : Some days ago I successfully compiled the kernel version. 5.4.244 with all the kvm flags enabled and the exynos 5250-snow.dtb file.